# Yanking URLs in w3m

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, clipboard, w3m

I have been using w3m for a couple of weeks and am convinced that it is my preferred text browser - with one exception.

Is there any way to yank URLs to the clipboard *without using the mouse*?

I have looked through [the manual](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL) and, using the default keybindings, there doesn't appear to be any documented way to do this.

Has anyone developed a script to work around this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the “External Browser” option to

```
sh -c 'printf %s "$0" | xsel'
```

You can use `xsel -b` to use the clipboard instead of the primary selection. An alternative to [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/) is [xclip](http://xclip.sourceforge.net) (`xclip` for the primary selection, `xclip -selection CLIPBOARD` for the clipboard).

In `~/.w3m/config`, that's the `extbrowser` setting.

Then [press `M`](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/MANUAL#Key%3aorig) to copy (yank) the URL of the current page, or `ESC M` to copy the URL of the link under the cursor.

You can use the second or third external browser for that instead; then the key combination is `2 M` or `3 M` or `2 ESC M` or `3 ESC M`.

Comment: I don't know if you cooked that up on the spot or it is a (little) known workaround, but it is both elegant & effective. Thank you.

Comment: [I did.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/925205#925205) I hadn't realized this was so easy before your question spurred me into looking! Thank you.

Comment: Colour me impressed :) To put the finishing touches on, I mapped some more intuitive keybinds, (the functions are EXTERN & EXTERN_LINK) and now I am set...

Comment: I think this won't work for magnet links, I am getting some Invalid directive errors.

Comment: Defining `extbrowser` ahead of time isn't required. If you run `2 ESC M` or `3 ESC M` when it isn't defined, it will prompt you for a command to run, which means you can run any program on the link. You could leave extbrowser 3 always open so as to have a command runner.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need a terminal emulator with a keyboard shortcut to paste test. For example, in Konsole you can do it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks minaev: that was a good suggestion. I installed http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/urxvt-url-yank but, alas, while it works in my term - it doesn't work in w3m...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [muennich/urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls)? Awesome scripts that can let you select/open URLs, select/copy with keyboard, and handle copy/paste from clipboard. Awesome scripts!

Comment: Yes, I have been using Bert's perls for a few years now. They don't work in w3m, however.

Answer (score 0):

you can yank url vim style, supports tmux,linux,macos,windows,android

```
$EDITOR ~/.w3m/keymap

# yank url to multiple clipboard (under cursor)
keymap  yy      EXTERN_LINK "url=%s ; printf "%b" "$url" > /tmp/clipbrd.txt ; printf "%b" "$url" | xsel -b 2>/dev/null ; printf "%b" "$url" | tmux load-buffer - ; printf '%s' "$url" | wl-copy 2>/dev/null  ; printf '%s' "$url" | clip 2>/dev/null ; printf '%s' "$url" > /dev/clipboard 2>/dev/null ; printf '%s' "$url" | pbcopy 2>/dev/null ; printf '%s' "$url" | termux-clipboard-set 2>/dev/null"

# yank url to multiple clipboard (current page)
keymap  YY      EXTERN "url=%s ; printf "%b" "$url" > /tmp/clipbrd.txt ; printf "%b" "$url" | xsel -b 2>/dev/null ; printf "%b" "$url" | tmux load-buffer - ; printf '%s' "$url" | wl-copy 2>/dev/null  ; printf '%s' "$url" | clip 2>/dev/null ; printf '%s' "$url" > /dev/clipboard 2>/dev/null ; printf '%s' "$url" | pbcopy 2>/dev/null ; printf '%s' "$url" | termux-clipboard-set 2>/dev/null"
```

usage:
go to a link and press **yy** to copy url