# How to turn off the help menu in Lynx

Tags: lynx, user-interface

I have a really small space reserved to Lynx for a quick lookup, as I need that often. However, the "Help" menu takes a lot of space and I don't really need it now.

[image]

The red oval is what I want to get rid of. How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press `o` to change the options. In the very first preference “User mode”, select “Advanced” (“Novice” has the huge help, “Intermediate” has a one-line help, and “Advanced” shows the selected URL in the modeline). Check the “Save options to disk” box then follow the “Accept” link at the top.

The corresponding setting in `~/.lynxrc` is

```
user_mode=ADVANCED
```

<sub>Aside: I prefer w3m to lynx. It has tabs, does better rendering and can show images. In its preferences, be sure to turn on “Display link URL automatically”. Also useful: [Yanking URLs in w3m](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12497/yanking-urls-in-w3m).</sub>

Comment: +1 for being 18 seconds quicker than me and including the config file option!

Comment: In my lynx web browser, through the [column80](http://www.column80.com) webapp I see the text in quotes of your answer as `â€œUser modeâ€�, select â€œAdvancedâ€�` any reason why this is so? The second answer appears fine.

Comment: @kuch These characters are non-ASCII characters (U+201c and U+201d). It looks like something took the UTF-8 bytes and rendered them as windows-1252. I don't know what's at fault here: column80, lynx or your settings.

Answer (score 2):

Set Lynx to advanced mode.  Options, user mode, advanced.

```
  General Preferences
  User mode                        : [Advanced___]
  Editor                           : ________
  Type of Search                   : [Case insensitive]
```