# Debian CLI torrent program through VPN

Tags: debian, vpn, openvpn, socks, bittorrent

Has anyone successfully set up a CLI-only (no web UI's!) torrent client that can tunnel all of its traffic through a VPN? (Either by sending all traffic through a particular interface or a SOCKS proxy)?

I have a [Private Internet Access](http://privateinternetaccess.com) subscription and would like to use it to download torrent files on my headless Debian 7 machine without having to tunnel all of the traffic on my system.

Comment: What sort of traffic would you want *not* to go through the VPN?

Comment: System updates, file downloads, really everything else.  Most importantly, if I tunnel all of the system traffic I lose the ability to contact it with SSH.

Answer (score 4):

The approach I would recommend is to route all your traffic through the VPN *except* SSH; this provides much more protection for your privacy and significantly reduces the risk of any personal information leaking.

This approach has several separate components.

### Torrent client

[rtorrent](http://rakshasa.github.io/rtorrent/) is an excellent torrent client for running in a headless environment. Run it in a [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) session so you can connect and disconnect at will.

Additionally, you can patch rtorrent with the [canvas colour](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2011/11/29/rtorrent/) patch.

### Routing traffic

Essentially, you want to set up packet filtering for all traffic on a specific port (your SSH port, here assumed to be non-standard 666) and interface (eth0). You can discover your gateway (here 192.168.1.1) with `route -n`. You will also need `iproute2` installed for this:

```
ip rule add fwmark 65 table novpn
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 table novpn
ip route flush cache
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 666 -j MARK --set-mark 65
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 666 -j DROP
```

Once you have it all setup and working, you'll need to script it to run at boot. See [Ben. D's answer on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/444631) for a full walkthrough.

### Browsing

[Surfraw](http://surfraw.alioth.debian.org/) is excellent for command line browsing, and can hand off to [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/) for loading the returned results.

Thanks to [Gilles excellent answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12497/yanking-urls-in-w3m/12572#12572), it is possible to bind a key in w3m to trigger the [magnets script](http://wiki.rtorrent.org/MagnetUri#Handling_.22magnet:.22_URIs_via_a_bash_script) from the rtorrent wiki. So, with this in your w3m config:

```
extbrowser /home/alex/bin/magnets %s
```

when you navigate to a magnet link, you can send it to rtorrent. See [this post for the details](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2013/06/29/raspberry/).