# Route everything through VPN except SSH on Port 22

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a server and I want to setup a VPN on it to route all traffic.

Of course I don't want to block myself out when establishing the OpenVPN connection (already did that!) so I want port 22 to be unaffected and be reachable as usual.

Is this possible? And if so, how can I set this up?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145783/6761

Comment: Set it all up accordingly (just port 22) but I still cant SSH onto server and have to do a hard reboot.  I am using Ubuntu 14.04 . Which OS did you use when u got it working? Also in your answer I think the part of echoing "201 novpn" into etc/iproute2/rt_tables is missing?

Comment: That's exactly how I set it up on Debian...

Comment: Alright thx. Ill try it again with a fresh Debian install.

Comment: Using Ubuntu should make no difference. Did you open port 22 in your firewall?

Comment: Im sshing onto the server on port 22. After setting everything up it still works fine. As soon as I start up OpenVPN though I only get TimeOuts when I try to connect to the server.

Comment: This is the script I run on boot: http://sprunge.us/XGCM

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20723/discussion-between-bananenmannfrau-and-jasonwryan).

Comment: besides , it is easier to write a route entry for the vpn host ip regardless of port . any reason we have to stick to the port ?

Comment: Could you post your solution? The VPN host would be germany.privateinternetaccess.com (dont know the exact IP right now).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add routing to your server so ssh packets get routed via the server's public ip not the vpn. Failing to do that means the ssh return packet gets routed via openvpn. This is why you get locked out of your server after you've inititated an openvpn client session.

Lets assume your server's:

- Public IP is `a.b.c.d`
- Public IP Subnet is `a.b.c.0/24`
- Default Gateway is `x.x.x.1`
- `eth0` is device to gateway

`iproute2` is your friend here. Do the following:

```
ip rule add table 128 from a.b.c.d
ip route add table 128 to a.b.c.0/24 dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via x.x.x.1
```

Do `route -n` to confirm new routing table shows up.
Above commands won't persists if you reboot the server. You'll need to add them to your network interface config file.

Then run your openvpn client config
`openvpn --config youropenvpn-configfile.ovpn &`

### Added bonus

Also, should you wish to restrict traffic to your public IP to ssh and only ssh then you'll need to add `iptables` filtering as follows:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d a.b.c.d -p tcp --dport <*ssh port number*> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -d a.b.c.d -j DROP
```

ps: I recall first learning about this in the Linode's forum - google it and you should be able to find a post on this.

Comment: Do I need the second command (`ip route add table 128 to a.b.c.0/24 dev eth0`) if I'm renting just one server from my hosting provider? Why does `traceroute` show that packets originating from my server are going through vpn network with your setup? Although, my server stays accessible when connected to VPN.

Comment: You can have just `ip route add table 128 to a.b.c.d` instead of `ip route add table 128 to a.b.c.0/24 dev eth0` if you only have 1 assigned IP, from what I understand.

Comment: Make sure you're using openvpn. I use the nordvpn binary to connect and this didn't work. When I connect to the NordVPN servers through openvpn, this works fine.

Comment: "You'll need to add them to your network interface config file." How to do that? How to make these changes persist?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your VPS Server Public IP is 1.2.3.4 and your VPN Public IP is 5.6.7.8

I would edit file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add a line:

```
ListenAddress 1.2.3.4
```

So SSHd would be accessible from outside the VPN connection.

Comment: The problem is that the outgoing packages are blocked. The SSH connection just times out on connecting.