# rdp disconnect aftter connect to vpn

Tags: centos, routing, vpn, remote, rdp

I want to connect to the server with rdp and connect to the vpn with the server. Is there a any way in centos to pass a specific port through a specific bridge interface, because whenever I connect to the vpn (on the server), the remote is disconnected.(through internet, local can connected)

## route

```
+ default via 192.168.1.1 dev tun0 
+ default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 
+ default dev tun0 scope link 
+ default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 src 192.168.1.16 metric 100 
+ default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.16 metric 100 
+ 104.237.240.165 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 src 192.168.1.16 metric 100 
+ 192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.16 metric 100 
+ 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 scope link 
+ 192.168.8.0/21 dev tun0 scope link
```

## ip

```
[dx@localhost ~]$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:a8:2a:14:45:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f0
    inet 192.168.1.16/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 423sec preferred_lft 423sec
    inet6 fe80::3ea8:2aff:fe14:455c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:a8:2a:14:45:5d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f1
4: eno3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:a8:2a:14:45:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f2
5: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:a8:2a:14:45:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f3
9: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1434 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.14.32/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::890c:a001:17cf:ee7f/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Related - [Debian CLI torrent program through VPN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145635/100397)

Comment: @roaima Thank you very much , thats work